# update-able background function(or other) in python

Tags: python, background-process

trying to make an idle game with 1 second ticks, I want to do a simple calculation in the background every second to add cash to the balance, honestly no clue how to start with this one.
need 'sheep' to be an update-able value while this runs

```
def gametime(cash, sheep):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        cash =+ (sheep)
```

Comment: Use multi-threading to run something in the background.